# Difference between gvim and macvim syntax highlighting

Tags: python, vim, macvim

This is purely a curiosity-only question.
I have noticed a difference between that when Macvim has syntax highlighting on, for python files, it makes a distinction between `else` and `else:`. The former it will recognoze as a keyword and highlight but not the latter. It does the same with other keywords like `except` and `finally`. This behavior is not present in the Windows version. I have noticed this with both versions 7.3 & 7.4.
Why is that? I thought they had the same code-base?

Answer (score 4):

They are built from the same code base but that code base is constantly evolving with patches merged in every couple of days non-stop since years. Whatever build you have is guaranteed to be outdated quite quickly.

For that reason, it's rather pointless to compare Vim between platforms or major versions. What counts is what we call the "patch-level": what patches were applied to the source when your Vim was built.

Additionally, Vim can be compiled with or without this or that feature which kind of complicates things.

Your 7.3 might be very different from my 7.3 at work and both will be very different from your 7.4 or mine, here at home.

When you compare Vim builds, you have to take the whole output of `:version` and, most importantly, the patch-level. My Vim 7.4 has patches 1 through 26 applied, as indicated by the 2nd line of `:version`:

```
Rustines incluses : 1-26
```

The discrepancy you are witnessing is probably due to some changes to the Python syntax files that intervened between builds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my guess would have been that there had to a difference in the python.vim file under the syntax folder and that is not the case. My second guess is that given both are the same, Vim on Windows uses a different pattern matcher than the one of OS X.